# ACF random image with correct caption

Tags: php, random, advanced-custom-fields, image-gallery

I'm trying to get a random image from an ACF gallery named `featured_image` with its corresponding image caption.

The image caption is added in the backend as a custom field on attachments named `featured_image_caption`.

It is working to get the random image from the gallery, however it won't echo the corresponding caption.

Where is this going wrong? It must be very close.

```php
<?php 
    $images = get_field('featured_image');
    $image_caption = get_field('featured_image_caption');
    $rand = array_rand($images, 1);
    if( $images ): ?>

    <section class="random-image">
        <figure>
            <img src="<?php echo $images[$rand]['url']; ?>" />
        </figure>
        <figcaption>
            <?php echo $image_caption; ?>
        </figcaption>
    </section>
            
<?php endif; ?>
```

**FINAL WORKING VERSION:**

```php
<?php 
    $images = get_field('featured_image');
    if( $images ):
    $rand = array_rand($images, 1);
    $image_caption = get_field('featured_image_caption', $images[$rand]['ID']); ?>

    <section class="random-image">
        <figure>
            <img src="<?php echo $images[$rand]['url']; ?>" />
        </figure>
        <figcaption>
            <?php echo $image_caption; ?>
        </figcaption>
    </section>
            
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I don't remember all of the fields that you get back when an image is in array format, but I think you can do something like `$image_caption = get_field('featured_image_caption', $rand['ID'])`

Comment: Thanks @ChrisHaas. That one didn't do the trick just yet–still doesn't output anything. Am I echoing the caption correctly in the example above to match with the way you get the caption?

Comment: How about `get_field('featured_image_caption', $images[$rand]['ID'])`

Comment: Thats it! Thanks @ChrisHaas. A slight rearrangement was needed for it to work. Question has been updated to show final version for those that need it.

Comment: Awesome. Technically, your `if` statement should come as the next line after the `$images` variable assignment, too